# Append on the same line bash

Tags: linux, bash, append

Using bash, I need to add to the end of a file, on the same line a string followed by the date. Example "Rebooted on Mon Aug 13 10:38:56 PDT 2012"

```
echo -n "Reboot done on " ; date
```

This gives me what I want on one line, but I can't append to the text file.

```
echo -n "Reboot done on " ; date > test.txt
```

This does not seem to work for me. It only gives me the date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want '>>' instead of '>' here if you truly want to append to the file, not overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Although, I was aware of that, just my question was formated poorly.

Answer (score 6):

This is because your output **Reboot done on** with echo and then you execute `date` and put its output into the file. Try this instead:

```
echo "Reboot done on $(date)" > test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
echo -n "Reboot done on `date`" > test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
(echo -n "Reboot done on "; date) > test.txt
```

Comment: `{ echo -n "..."; date; }` would also concatenate the output streams, without spawning a subshell.